# How I can check if an object is null in ruby on rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to check when my object `@objectname` is not equal to null to show the values of the `@objectname` else to show that no values found.

I tried this:

```
<% if (@objectname != null) then %>
```

but I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

it's `nil`in Ruby, not `null`. And it's enough to say `if @objectname` to test whether it's not nil. And no `then`. You can find more on `if` syntax here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#if

Comment: It would also be advisable to play with `rails console` to try out statements on the fly

Comment: im having this one if @reviews.nil? then and always is true even there is a review or not

Comment: there should be no `then` in your `if`. You might also want to explain a bit more about how you populate the `@reviews` (if it is in fact `.nil?` all the time) for us to give you some more ideas.

Comment: ~Pavel Veller, the then is optional, but I wouldn't say that there should be no then used.

Comment: @reviews is probably an array, and an empty array is still true.   try `empty?`, or as said above, `present?` or `blank?`

Comment: ~George, print out reviews (before the if) to verify that it's not nil.  <%= @reviews.inspect %>

Answer (score 46):

You can check if an object is nil (null) by calling present? or blank? .

```
@object.present?
```

this will return false if the project is an empty string or nil .

or you can use

```
@object.blank?
```

this is the same as present? with a bang and you can use it if you don't like 'unless'.
this will return true for an empty string or nil .

Comment: `#blank?` and `#present?` have other implications than just whether the object is `nil`. And `then`, while uncommon, is fine in Ruby if statements.

Comment: Should also be noted that `#present?` and `#blank?` are only available in Rails and don't exist in vanilla Ruby.

Answer (score 21):

Now with Ruby 2.3 you can use `&.` operator ('lonely operator') to check for `nil` at the same time as accessing a value.

```
@person&.spouse&.name
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Other_operators

---

Use `#try` instead so you don't have to keep checking for `nil`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

```
@person.try(:spouse).try(:name)
```

instead of

```
@person.spouse.name if @person && @person.spouse
```

Answer (score 5):

In your example, you can simply replace `null` with `nil and it will work fine.

```
require 'erb'

template = <<EOS
<% if (@objectname != nil) then %>
  @objectname is not nil
<% else %>
  @objectname is nil
<% end %>
EOS

@objectname = nil
ERB.new(template, nil, '>').result # => "  @objectname is nil\n"

@objectname = 'some name'
ERB.new(template, nil, '>').result # => "  @objectname is not nil\n"
```

Contrary to what the other poster said, you can see above that `then` works fine in Ruby. It's not common, but it is fine.

`#blank?` and `#present?` have other implications. Specifically, if the object responds to `#empty?`, they will check whether it is empty. If you go to http://api.rubyonrails.org/ and search for "blank?", you will see what objects it is defined on and how it works. Looking at the [definition on Object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F), we see *"An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, “”, “ ”, nil, [], and {} are all blank."* You should make sure that this is what you want.

Also, nil is considered false, and anything other than false and nil is considered true. This means you can directly place the object in the if statement, so a more canonical way of writing the above would be

```
require 'erb'

template = <<EOS
<% if @objectname %>
  @objectname is not nil
<% else %>
  @objectname is nil
<% end %>
EOS

@objectname = nil
ERB.new(template, nil, '>').result # => "  @objectname is nil\n"

@objectname = 'some name'
ERB.new(template, nil, '>').result # => "  @objectname is not nil\n"
```

If you explicitly need to check `nil` and not `false`, you can use the `#nil?` method, for which nil is the only object that will cause this to return true.

```
nil.nil?          # => true
false.nil?        # => false
Object.new.nil?   # => false
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simple not flag to validate that.
Example

```
if !@objectname
```

This will return true if @objectname is nil.
You should not use dot operator or a nil value, else it will throw

> *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `isNil?' for nil:NilClass

An ideal nil check would be like:

```
!@objectname || @objectname.nil? || @objectname.empty?
```